# Socket io not broadcasting to specific room

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to broadcast some info to a specific room:

**server side**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, { path: '/my/path' });
server.listen(8090, function () {
    console.log("Server ON.");
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('room', function(room) { //set the room
        socket.join(room);
        socket.room = room;
    });
    socket.on('new message', function (data) { //receive and broadcast the msg
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

**client side**

```
//initial client config
var socket = io(URL_SOCKET, {path: '/my/path'});
socket.emit('room', room_id);
socket.on('new message', function (data) {
    do_something(data);
});

function on_change(data){
    socket.emit('new message', data);
}
```

**The problem here is:** the `socket.broadcast.to` is broadcasting the information sent by clients (by calling `on_change`) to all the rooms (to everyone). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hava a look at https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/emit.md - you may want to try `socket.to(socket.room).emit` or `io.to(socket.room).emit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
io.in(socket.room).emit('requestRes',{success:true,STATUSCODE:2000,message:"hello"});
```

try for searching Socket cheat sheet.
ps:https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/#

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip, I was using `socket.io` with `browser sync`, that also uses it, and I was getting conflicts. So just be sure to turn the ghost mode off before test your socket application.